# Numpy way for building NXD matrix from multipication of matrix and elemets of vector

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a vector, v which is of size D, and I want to multiply it by each element of the vector y, which is of size N, such that each column i of a new Matrix X is the product of v and the indexed element of the vector y.
I'm trying to avoid of creating an empty NXD matrix and run with a for loop on all the elements in y, multiply with v, and copy them to the new empty matrix.
If there is an efficient way to do that, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `numpy.outer()`:

```
X = np.outer(v, y)
```